# Sed variable increment

Tags: sed

I have this code:

```
for ((a=1; a <= 6; a++)); do 
    sed -i 's/^.*$/'$a'.mp4/' *.html; 
    echo "$a"; 
    sleep 0.2; 
done
```

the problem is, I always get 6 from `$a` and I need to get 1 for first file, 2 for the second and so on a roll

Comment: Your code unconditionally replaces every (nonempty) line of the file with a specific string. You don't need `sed` for that.

Comment: What exactly is the input and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're editing every file each time through the loop, not one file per iteration.

You need to loop through the files, not the values of `a`.

```
a=1
for file in *.html; do
    sed -i 's/^.*$/'$a'.mp4/' "$file"
    echo "$a"
    sleep 0.2
    ((a++))
done
```